# Oracle apex: adding filters programmatically with dynamic action adds duplicate filters

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have several dynamic actions that are fired with change event on page load. It seems like all of them are fired at same time. When that happens it adds filter to the interactive grid. Now, the problem is some of the filters are duplicated. How can I solve this problem?

I mean when page loads, it changes bunch of things in the form (like checkboxes and values of textfield), that fires the dynamic action, which then calls addFilter function like this

```
function newFilter(){
    var vals = apex.item('P12_VALUE').getValue();

    if(!(vals.includes('DI'))){
         deleteExistingFilters('emp', 'IS_ON');
    }

    if(vals.includes('DI')){
        if(!filterAlreadyExist('emp', 'IS_ON')){
            addFilter('emp', 'IS_ON','Y','EQ');
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "with change event on page load" mean? When do you want to add the filters? Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 0):

Create only one dynamic action that fires on page load, but let it execute several ("true"?) actions, i.e. every action would be one or none of those "several" dynamic actions you have now. "None" means that you'd exclude it if it is already set.